# fputcsv doesn't write any data in a CSV file

Tags: php, csv, fputcsv

In my web site I'm creating a table from the mysql data and then now I want to add a export button buttom of the table so that a user will be able to download the data as an CSV file.

To do that I wrote dummy form:

```
<form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Click Me">
</form>
```

And at the top of the php file I have:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    export();
}
```

In my export function I have some mysql stuff, I'm creating an array and pushing data into it, and then:

```
$header = array('name', 'date', 'total', 'success', 'opens', 'clicks', 'success_rate', 'open_rate', 'CTO', 'CTR')
$fp = fopen('exportme2.csv', 'w');
fputcsv($fp, $header);

foreach ($data as $lines) {
        fputcsv($fp, $lines);
}
fclose($fp);
```

After I click to export button, I'll have exportme2.csv file, however it is empty !
The data may be wrong so that there won't be anything but at least I should have the header names.

Can you help me about this issue please ?

Thanks.

Comment: Does the header row exist in the data file, or is the entire file empty?

Comment: Have you checked the return values of `fputcsv`?

Comment: Did you check if the file is even opened? `$fp` would be boolean false on failure.

Comment: all file was empty, instead of refreshing the page, i entered the page again, now I have the header titles. But no data too :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wasn't posting anything because it submit the page so that when the page refreshed all of my arrays are become empty.

Answer (score 2):

First off, change

```
$fp = fopen('exportme2.csv', 'w');
```

to

```
$fp = fopen('exportme2.csv', 'a');
```

as `'w'` *truncates* the file, where `'a'` creates or *appends* the file.

Then you should use `flock()` to make sure two different users (threads) don't try to write to the file at the same time:

```
if (!flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) {
    error_log('Cannot get lock!');
} else {
    fputcsv($fp, $header);

    foreach ($data as $lines) {
        fputcsv($fp, $lines);
    }
}
```

If that doesn't fix things, then you have a typo in your code somewhere that isn't obvious to me.

Answer (score 1):

This is running good for me :

```
$header = array('name', 'date', 'total', 'success', 'opens', 'clicks', 'success_rate', 'open_rate', 'CTO', 'CTR');
$fp = fopen('exportme2.csv', 'w');
fputcsv($fp, $header);

/*foreach ($data as $lines) {
    fputcsv($fp, $lines);
}*/
fclose($fp);
```

Your above script stopped before the fclose, so it bugged your file ...
You should develop with the E_ALL E_STRICT enabled !